# Covariance function for a Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be a standard Brownian motion. For $t\geq 0$, define
$$U(t) = e^{-t}B(e^{2t}).$$
The problem is to determine the covariance function of the process.
Supposedly, the answer is $e^{-s-t}$.

Initially, I thought $U(t)$ followed a standard normal distribution because of scaling, but apparently I was mistaken.
My next attempt was to let $0\leq s<t$ and
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}[e^{-s}B(e^{2s}),e^{-t}B(e^{2t})] &= e^{-s-t}\text{Cov}[B(e^{2s}),B(e^{2t})]\\
&= e^{-s-t}E[\{B(e^{2s})\}^2]
\end{align*}
after a few steps, using the fact that independent blocks of time
yield zero mean. If $e^{-s-t}$ is the correct answer, this suggests that 
$E[\{B(e^{2s})\}^2] = 1$.

My questions are

1. Why isn't $U(t)$ standard normal?
2. Why $E[\{B(e^{2s})\}^2] = 1$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}[U(s),U(t)] &= e^{-s-t}\text{Cov}[B(e^{2s}),B(e^{2t})]\\
&= e^{-s-t}(e^{2s}\wedge e^{2t})=e^{t\wedge s-t\vee s}
\end{align*}

Also

$$U(t)\overset{d}{=}e^{-t}\sqrt{e^{2t}}B(1)=B(1)\sim N(0, 1)$$